# Kivy - Getting Black Screen

Tags: python, kivy

Why am i getting a black screen? The Code worked fine 10 minutes ago.
What's wrong with the Code, i cannot see anything wrong! Also i cannot find any solution for that online! Do you guys know how to fix the Problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import kivy

kivy.require("1.10.0")

import os
import humanize
from glob import glob
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class Layout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Layout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

     def scan(self):
        pass          
        scanb = Button(text="Scan",background_color=(1,0,1,1),font_size=(50))
        title = Label(text="StorageCleaner",font_size=(50),size_hint=(.1,.2),background_color=(1,0,0,1))

        self.add_widget(title)
        self.add_widget(copy)
        scanb.bind(on_press=scan)

class StorageCleaner(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = Layout()
        return layout

sc = StorageCleaner()

if __name__ == "__main__":
       sc.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few errors. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.0")

import os
import humanize
from glob import glob
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Layout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1

        scanb = Button(text="Scan", font_size=50)
        scanb.bind(on_press=self.scan)
        title = Label(text="StorageCleaner", font_size=50, size_hint=(.1, .2))

        self.add_widget(title)
        self.add_widget(scanb)

    def scan(self):
        pass


class StorageCleaner(App):

    def build(self):
        return Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    StorageCleaner().run()
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

Might be the indentation after 'pass' in your scan function. Looks like 'scanb', 'title', etc, is indented one level too much